Supabase Email OTP Not Working Due to Session Error
Currently working with NextJS and Supabase
I have an issue relating to Supabase's Email provider, more specifically with Email OTP. I can correctly receive a OTP to an email that I enter on my login page (/login), however after clicking login, I do not get redirected to my desired page, which is a dashboard component (/dashboard).
I have included debugging messages that follow my OTP workflow.
GET /login 200 in 5ms
 ✓ Compiled in 42ms (237 modules)
Middleware triggered for path: /auth/callback
Middleware session check: Not found 
Allowing auth callback to proceed
 ✓ Compiled /auth/callback in 245ms (1646 modules)
 ⚠ Fast Refresh had to perform a full reload. Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/fast-refresh-reload
Auth callback triggered
Auth code received: No
No code or session, redirecting to login
 GET /auth/callback 307 in 334ms
Middleware triggered for path: /login
Middleware session check: Not found 
 GET /login 200 in 93ms

It seems that despite my session handling, a valid session is not being created.
I have attached my code below. It consists of three parts: middleware.ts which is the middleware handler, auth/callback/route.ts which is the callback logic, and handleVerifyCode() which is a function that exists on my login component.
middleware.ts
import { createMiddlewareClient } from '@supabase/auth-helpers-nextjs'
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server'
import type { NextRequest } from 'next/server'

export async function middleware(req: NextRequest) {
  const res = NextResponse.next()
  const supabase = createMiddlewareClient({ req, res })

  try {
    const { data: { session }, error } = await supabase.auth.getSession()
    if (error) {
      console.error('Error fetching session:', error)
    }

    // Debug logs
    console.log('Middleware path:', req.nextUrl.pathname)
    console.log('Session status:', session ? 'Found' : 'Not found')

    if (!session && req.nextUrl.pathname.startsWith('/dashboard')) {
      console.log('No session found, redirecting to /login')
      return NextResponse.redirect(new URL('/login', req.url))
    }

    if (session && req.nextUrl.pathname === '/login') {
      console.log('Session exists, redirecting to /dashboard')
      return NextResponse.redirect(new URL('/dashboard', req.url))
    }

    return res
  } catch (err) {
    console.error('Middleware error:', err)
    return NextResponse.redirect(new URL('/login', req.url))
  }
}

export const config = {
  matcher: ['/dashboard/:path*', '/login', '/auth/callback']
}

route.ts (auth/callback/route.ts)
import { createRouteHandlerClient } from '@supabase/auth-helpers-nextjs'
import { cookies } from 'next/headers'
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server'

export async function GET(request: Request) {
  console.log('Auth callback triggered')
  const requestUrl = new URL(request.url)
  const code = requestUrl.searchParams.get('code')
  
  console.log('Auth code received:', code ? 'Yes' : 'No')

  if (code) {
    const supabase = createRouteHandlerClient({ cookies })
    console.log('Exchanging code for session...')
    
    try {
      const { data, error } = await supabase.auth.exchangeCodeForSession(code)
      
      if (error) {
        console.error('Auth error during exchange:', error)
        return NextResponse.redirect(new URL('/login', request.url))
      }

      if (data?.session) {
        // Explicitly set the session
        await supabase.auth.setSession(data.session)
        console.log('Session set successfully, redirecting to dashboard')
        return NextResponse.redirect(new URL('/dashboard', request.url))
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Unexpected error during auth:', error)
      return NextResponse.redirect(new URL('/login', request.url))
    }
  }

  console.log('No code or session, redirecting to login')
  return NextResponse.redirect(new URL('/login', request.url))
}```

and finally, handleVerifyCode() (/login)
const handleVerifyCode = async (e: React.FormEvent) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setLoading(true);
    console.log('Starting OTP verification...');

    try {
      const { data, error } = await supabase.auth.verifyOtp({
        email,
        token: code,
        type: 'email',
      });
      console.log('OTP verification response:', { data, error });

      if (error) throw error;

      if (data?.session) {
        console.log('Session verified, redirecting to dashboard');
        router.push('/dashboard');
      } else {
        throw new Error('No session returned from OTP verification');
      }
    } catch (error: any) {
      console.error('Error verifying code:', error.message);
      alert(error.message);
    } finally {
      setLoading(false);
    }
  };


